# Convert the Java list sort(..) lambda expression to kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following 2 lists:

```
 ArrayList<String> staticlist = new ArrayList<String>()
        staticlist.add("Dairy")
        staticlist.add("Food")
        staticlist.add("Juice")
        staticlist.add("Bakery")
        staticlist.add("Poultry")

ArrayList<String> mySortedItems= new ArrayList<String>()
       staticlist.add("Food")
        staticlist.add("Poultry")
        staticlist.add("Juice")
        staticlist.add("Bakery")
```

In java sorting mysortedItems according to staticlist works like this:

```
mySortedItems.sort((s1,s2)-> Integer.compare(mySortedItems.indexOf(s1),mySortedItems.indexOf(s1)))
```

Now how to convert this into kotlin?

The API level should be maintained to 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your Java file to Kotlin from context menu or Android Studio suggests you to convert your Java code if you insert it in kt file. Eventually you will get something like this:

```
    val staticlist = ArrayList<String>()
    staticlist.add("Dairy")
    staticlist.add("Food")
    staticlist.add("Juice")
    staticlist.add("Bakery")
    staticlist.add("Poultry")

    val mySortedItems = ArrayList<String>()
    mySortedItems .add("Food")
    mySortedItems .add("Poultry")
    mySortedItems .add("Juice")
    mySortedItems .add("Bakery")

    mySortedItems.sortWith(Comparator { s1, s2 -> staticlist.indexOf(s1).compareTo(staticlist.indexOf(s2)) })
```

Comment: I used an online converter and it turned out to be horrible, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Bracadabra's answer will work fine, but if you look at the lambda you can notice it compares the same function applied to `s1` and `s2`, which means it can be simplified using [`sortBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html):

```
mySortedItems.sortBy { staticlist.indexOf(it) }
```

(From "sorting mysortedItems according to staticlist" I assume you wanted to use `staticlist.indexOf(s1)` and not `mySortedItems.indexOf(s1)`)

Use `sortedBy` to return a new sorted list instead if you want.

As additional note, instead of creating an empty list and adding each element to it, the preferred Kotlin style is to call

```
val staticlist = listOf("Dairy", "Food", "Juice", "Bakery", "Poultry")
```

or `mutableListOf`/`arrayListOf`/etc. depending on the desired type.